# Installing libevent via PECL fails on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, pecl

I have Ubuntu 12.04 built with Moodle Stack installed. I'm trying to install this:

```
$ sudo pecl install libevent
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to download pecl/libevent within preferred state "stable", latest release is 
version 0.0.5, stability "beta", use "channel://pecl.php.net/libevent-0.0.5" to install
install failed
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem - as the error message states - is the package being in beta state. In order to install a beta package, you need to add the `-beta` post fix [as mentioned in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.pear.php). So your installation command would be:

```
$ sudo pecl install libevent-beta
```

The correct search term for this on Google would have been:

> pecl beta